# How do I stop a process running in IntelliJ such that it calls the shutdown hooks?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I run my program in IntelliJ then use the STOP button, it does not call my shutdown hooks that I've created. Is there a way in IntelliJ to have those called on shutdown?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You need to use the **Exit** button in the **Run** panel, not the Stop button. Note that it will only work when Running and will not work when Debugging.

Here is the screenshot if you can't find it:

[image: Exit button]

Old versions:

[image: Exit]

This feature uses platform specific code and currently works on Windows and Linux only. <s>Once [IDEA-56273](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-56273) is fixed, this feature should be also available on Mac.</s> It is fixed in 10.5 version of IDEA.

Comment: hrm, I'm totally missing where the "Exit" button is, do you happen to have a screenshot handy? thanks so much

Comment: Updated my reply with a screenshot.

Comment: that's really weird, here's my runtime panel http://www.dropmocks.com/mPyzF  I don't see that icon. i'm using intellij 10

Comment: Taking thread dumps and performing graceful shutdown depends on the native component which is currently not available for Mac platform. Updated my reply.

Comment: Do you know why this isn't available from the Debugger?

Comment: Running on windows with Intellij 13.1.3 and also don't have this button.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, would be really great to know, Tom already asked, why this isn't available for Debug Sessions or when this will be available for Debug sessions.

Comment: Was the "Exit" button removed for OSX? Currently using 15.0.4 and I don't have access to this.

Comment: I have the Exit button on OS X running 2016.1 EAP, and when I click it it does appear to call the shutdown hooks, but it appears to leave the java process behind, which I discovered because it does not release the debug port it was listening on and as such I am unable to start a new instance of my application. I had to kill the java process with Activity Monitor.

Comment: I've been using Intellij for years and this is the first time I've used that "exit" icon - to test shutdown hooks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It still works for Idea 2022.2.1 on Windows

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac (and I assume Linux), get the pid and use kill from the terminal.  It's an extra step, but works to debug the shutdown handler when you need to.