# Java Shutdown function not executing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Within the main() of my application I have the following code to back up data so it doesn't get lost in the event of a system shut down.

```
    //add hook to trigger Production Shutdown sequence
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Production.shutdown();
        }
    }));
```

However, whether I press the `Stop` button in my IDE or rely on input via the log (code shown below) it never seems to save data to the database or write any logs to the console.

```
    ctx.deploy(server);

    server.start();

    //start the production process
    Production.init();

    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
```

How come this shutdown function is not being executed?

Comment: Is there code that calls `System.exit` when a shutdown happens?  If you're having trouble finding any, maybe install a security manager that logs attempts to exit.

Comment: Why don't you shutdown() at the end of `main()` instead?

Comment: @fge There could be multiple threads besides `main`. If there are, the program will shutdown while the other threads are doing other stuff, causing problems.

Comment: @gparyani sure, this can happen if you lose the reference to what you want to shut down in main, but if you do so I'd question your sanity ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the `Exit` button, not `Stop`, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727696/104891) for more details.

Note that this feature is currently available only in Run mode, not in Debug.

Comment: Just today I found about stop button ignoring shutdown hooks as well. Personally I think it's a very bad decision, I always thought Stop button simulates Ctrl+C (that is SIGINT on unix). And then there is debug without that Exit button. You can try to kill process knowing its PID (`jps` can help), right? Wrong... Using Windows and its `taskkill` process cannot be stopped in normal way - only forcefully (`taskkill /f /pid x`) - it seems IDE is somehow "protecting" it (both in debug and normal run). This doesn't make testing of shutdown hooks any easier. Debugging just plain impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.exit(0)
```

add this line in your code. Debug from here onwards