# How can I get IntelliJ debugger to allow my app's shutdown hooks to run?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, shutdown-hook, intellij-13

When debugging in IntelliJ an app that registers shutdown hooks, the shutdown hooks do not get called if I click the green "restart" circular arrow button, nor if I click the red square "stop" button. In both cases it appears the app-under-debug is immediately forcibly terminated.

(Note this is not a duplicate of [How do I stop a processing running in intelliJ such that it calls the shutdown hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727536/how-do-i-stop-a-processing-running-in-intellij-such-that-it-calls-the-shutdown-h))

When I "manually" send the debugger process an INT signal from the Mac Terminal, of course then my shutdown hooks run as expected. But I haven't been able to discover any configuration settings or controls within the IDE that provoke the desired behavior.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please have a look at the [corresponding issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75946) in JetBrains bugtracker.

I've just tested that on Idea 14.0.2 - Stop button is working gracefully so that shutdown hooks are executed.

Unfortunately, you can't use breakpoints in your shutdown hook body when you use Stop button: these breakpoints are silently ignored.

**If you need to debug your shutdown hook code** (i.e. stop on breakpoints), you could gracefully shutdown your application running in IDEA's debug by calling a command from terminal:

```
kill -INT <pid>
```

where `pid` is your application's process ID and could be found, for example by following command:

```
ps ax | grep java | grep <MainClassNameYouRun>
```

In this case IDEA will stop on breakpoints in shutdown hook.

Comment: "Unfortunately, you can't use breakpoints in your shutdown hook body" Thats what I came here for. Thanks.