# Intellij IDEA 13 Exit Button

Tags: intellij-idea, exit, intellij-13

[How do I stop a processing running in intelliJ such that it calls the shutdown hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727536/how-do-i-stop-a-processing-running-in-intellij-such-that-it-calls-the-shutdown-h/4727696#4727696)

This is the button that I'm looking for, but my "Run" area is missing this button. After I *accidently* hit stop, I have to go manually kill the process.

How can I get this button?

[image]