# Why does Spring Boot application not exit gracefully?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am running a Spring Boot application using `bootRun` task in **Intellij (13.1.5 on Linux)**, and I am trying to shut down a listener thread in the lifecycle callback, however when stopping the app in IntelliJ, I find my listener thread is still running and logging.

1. In Console:

   > "Disconnected from the target VM, address: ..., transport: 'socket'
   >   6:39:22 AM: External task execution finished 'bootRun'."
2. Then I did ps grep and kill the process, 
   only then console prints:

   > "2016-03-28 06:39:59.606  INFO 7740 --- [       Thread-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@657617e6: ...2016-03-28 06:39:59.611  INFO 7740 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown"

**My Questions:**

1. Why stopping app in Intellij not closing application context?
2. Accodring to Doc, Spring Web app automatically registers shutdown hooks. But I have tried `@PreDestroy`, `destroyMethod`, and implements `LifeCycle`, why does none of them get called?

Comment: I am having the same issue. You're supposed to click the Exit icon (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727536/how-do-i-stop-a-processing-running-in-intellij-such-that-it-calls-the-shutdown-h) instead of Stop in order to get a graceful shutdown, but it still doesn't call my @PreDestroy method. I have also tried implementing DisposableBean and creating an applicationListener (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678208/spring-boot-shutdown-hook).

Nothing works!

Comment: @JakeRobb I'm not sure that will work. OP is executing bootRun which is a task you get out of the box with spring boot. Due to the nature of spring boot the web server is embedded and thus intellij won't be awere that a web server is even running. All it would see is a running gradle task as it makes a JAR not a WAR

Comment: Yes, as I said, it doesn’t work. I wasn’t suggesting a solution.

Comment: As a workaround you can use actuator's endpoint [shutdown](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) to trigger the graceful shutdown.