# Send SIGINT to running program in IntelliJ

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, sigint

As IntelliJ + Windows user, I'm running some applications by starting some "Configurations".

The "Tool windows"/"Run" live show my aplication logs, and I've got left panel with "pause" or "stop" buttons. The stop button send a **SIGKILL** to the application thread.
[image]

I would like a **new button to send a SIGINT (CTRL + C equivalent) to my application**.

I already saw lots of issues about "sending SIGINT on Windows environment" and it seems that it's not an easy task.

I also saw a 3 years old IntelliJ issue (already OPEN) about that point [CPP-3067](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3067)

After some search, I found this project called [windows-kill](https://github.com/alirdn/windows-kill) that fit my need: *I can take the application pid, and use this project binary to send a SIGINT on windows environment.*

```
windows-kill -SIGINT 1234
```

My queston is:

- how to add a new button on "Tool windows"/"Run" ? and is it possible to inject current thread pid for this new command ?

If it's not possible, I would like to know how to start to develop a new IntelliJ plugin: for example a new "ToolWindows" called "TaskManager" that

- list all thread name+pid started by IntelliJ configurations,
- allow user to define button+command for a given pid.

Maybe there is some open-source plugin that already doing  that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727696/104891. Note that it's not available for all configuration types.

Comment: I feel so dumb to not try this one (exit button) wich is documented https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-tool-window.html 
Note that the button is not available for Run/Debug Configuration: Node.js, Run/Debug Configuration: Attach to Node.js/Chrome, and Run/Debug Configuration: NodeUnit.