# Interrupt running Java code without immediately killing the application, but letting Interrupt signal, time to finish processing?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executorservice, interrupt-handling

I have a Java Spring Boot app, that has a class @Component, with @SqsListener`receive` method, listening on AWS SQS queue, pulling in messages and creating Callable tasks using `this.executorService.submit(taskResults)`

For context:
`Callable<Result> resultFuture = new ProcessingTask(various attributes and data sent over)`

Then I have a LinkedList of List<Future>, holding my futures on the singleton.
then, every time `receive` is invoked, I check the size of the list, if it is more than twice the `availableProcessors`, I invoke a helper method that is iterating over the LinkedList, each Future, I check `isDone`, if it is, then I do a .get to retrieve results - at this point I implemented catchers for InterruptedException, ExecutionException as well as checking `Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()` on every significant step in the `call` method of my ProcessingTask implementation.

I am not sure entirely how to test this complete set of rules, but I started with something simple:
Run the app in IDEA, then submit messages into SQS for processing - it picks up everything looks good.

Then I submitted large message to process, and while it is in middle of processing, I hit the red Stop button in IDEA, expecting it to raise Interrupted flag for the threads to gracefully exit - however this did not happen, it kills everything immediately, none of my interrupt code log statements anywhere were called.

So my questions I guess are:

1. How to send Interrupt signal while running in IDEA, to test stuff?
2. Any references on testing multi processing and interruption logic please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4727696/104891.

Comment: Thank you, it didnt  show up in my searches which were focused on interrupt keyword :)