# Difficulty to understand when is shutdown hook executed and how to terminate an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, shutdown-hook

I'm trying to run a program based on a `scheduleAtFixedRate` `ExecutorService`.
I use this service to replace a dummy `while` loop.
The global idea is to have first an `ExecutorService` (the scheduler) executing a `Runnable` (the runnable). then, for some reason, the runnable may or may not schedule a task on an other `ExecutorService` (the tasker).
Now the question is :

- *how am I suppose to stop all these Threads when I stop the program ?*

I have experimented a bit and can't find a proper solution.
I have tried two things : `DaemonThread`, `ShutdownHook`
Daemon threads are not what I'm looking for, I want the scheduler to keep running until I stop the program.
A ShutdownHook was not a good solution at first sight but after some researches it seems to work.

- **I just don't understand why**.

The thing is, the ShutdownHook is runned if I execute the code with the command `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.goodbook.App"` and stop it with `Ctrl+C`, but it's not executed if I run the java code in my IDE (VScode) and stop it with the debugger tool.
So there are two more question :

- *Why is the `ShutdownHook` executed ?*
- *Why is the behavior diffrent between running with the command line and running with the IDE*

First I will give you two pieces of code : the App and the Task class.

---

### App.java

```
package com.goodbook;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class ShutdownHook {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShutdownHook.class);
  public void attachShutDownHook(ScheduledExecutorService scheduler, ScheduledExecutorService tasker) {
    logger.info("attaching shutdown hook");
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        scheduler.shutdown();
        tasker.shutdown();
        logger.info("shutdown hook runned");
        logger.info("scheduler is down : "+scheduler.isShutdown());
        logger.info("tasker is down : "+tasker.isShutdown());
      }
    });
  }
}

public class App 
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {   
    logger.info("starting program");
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
    ScheduledExecutorService tasker = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);

    ShutdownHook shutdown = new ShutdownHook();
    shutdown.attachShutDownHook(scheduler, tasker);

    Task t = new Task("task1");

    Runnable  runnable = () -> {
      logger.info("running Tasker 1");
      if(!t.isPlanified()){
        logger.info("unplanified task found "+t.getName());
        logger.info("planning...");
        tasker.schedule(t, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        t.setPlanified(true);
      }
    };
    logger.info("scheduling tasks");
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } 
}
```

### Task.java

```
package com.goodbook;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Task implements Runnable {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

  String name;
  AtomicBoolean planified = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public Task(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    logger.info(name+" run");
    planified.set(false);
  }

  public Boolean isPlanified(){
    return planified.get();
  }

  public void setPlanified(Boolean b){
    planified.set(b);
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

The end of the log file in the case of running with VScode and stopping execution with the debugger tool:

```
INFO    2019-04-06 16:35:54,121 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - planning...
INFO    2019-04-06 16:35:55,121 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - Running Tasker 1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:35:55,121 [pool-2-thread-4] com.goodbook.TestTask  - task1 run
INFO    2019-04-06 16:35:56,121 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - Running Tasker 1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:35:56,121 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - Unplanified task found task1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:35:56,121 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - planning...
```

The end of the log file in the case of running with `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.goodbook.App"` and stopping execution with `Ctrl+C`:

```
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:09,686 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - running Tasker 1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:09,688 [pool-2-thread-1] com.goodbook.Task  - task1 run
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:10,686 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - running Tasker 1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:10,686 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - unplanified task found task1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:10,687 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - planning...
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:11,686 [pool-1-thread-1] com.goodbook.App  - running Tasker 1
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:11,687 [pool-2-thread-2] com.goodbook.Task  - task1 run
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:12,641 [Thread-1] com.goodbook.ShutdownHook$1  - shutdown hook runned
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:12,642 [Thread-1] com.goodbook.ShutdownHook$1  - scheduler is down : true
INFO    2019-04-06 16:59:12,642 [Thread-1] com.goodbook.ShutdownHook$1  - tasker is down : true
```

I really need help with these problems, I'm not a java dev :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shutdown hooks are called when the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) is shutting down; see the class JavaDoc at [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html). But terminating a run from a debugger is *not* a shutdown.

## Usual exit

When either the last non-[daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213340/642706) exits, or [`System.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) is called via code, or [CTRL-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) is pressed on the command line, (or the program is sent a kill signal, eg. using task manager), then the shutdown hooks are executed, and once they have completed, the JVM shuts down.

## Exit from debugger

If you terminate the program during debugging, and press "stop", the [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) **aborts your app immediately**. There is no chance to run the shutdown hooks. This is usually the right thing to do; when debugging, you normally want to *just kill* whatever is running.

## Exiting gracefully while debugging

If you want a way to run the shutdown hooks while debugging, there are a number of ways; one is calling [`System.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) via code; that will trigger the hooks. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547169/how-to-get-shutdown-hook-to-execute-on-a-process-launched-from-eclipse) related question, they wait for a keypress event before calling system.exit.

---

Regarding

> how am I supposed to stop all these Threads when I stop the program ?

again, you can call [`System.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) so that the program will terminate even if non-deamon threads are in the middle of an execution (which is not really clean); but a better way is to give every thread a chanche to terminate normally- eg. if a thread is running an infinite loop, it could periodically check a (volatile) `shutdown` variable, and return (via code) when the variable becomes set. (the `shutdown` variable itself should be set by a shutdown hook)

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I can't use a `System.exit` while debugging because it will run in the main thread and be executed regardless of the `ScheduledExecutorService`. I guess I will just debug from the command line...
The other point : why is the `shutdownHook`executed needs a bit more explanations in my opinion. I thought this hook is runned only if all the Threads in the JVM are stopped but I may have misunderstood. I shut down the threads in the shut down hook, if this is acceptable I will stick with this design.